# Pass the hash/ pass the ticket TO a linux machine

Tags: linux, active-directory, pass-the-hash

I'm studying how to attack AD, but so far I have seen how to use pass the hash and pass the ticket to get access to Windows machines. How does one attack Linux machines joined to the domain using the same technique? I could not find anything on the web.

ps: I'm not looking for how to harvest tickets or hashes from a Linux machine, but how to use them to get access to a Linux machine

Comment: I googled your question title and got https://www.n00py.io/2020/12/alternative-ways-to-pass-the-hash-pth/ as the top hit that offers options